# Can I bookmark a question and check back later?

Tags: feature-request

Some question raised by other users interested me. I want to bookmark it and check back later (see whether good response come up). Is this feature exist?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, click the little star button below the up/down vote arrows to favorite a post. This will bookmark it for you.

To see all your favorited posts, simply go to your profile and click on favorites.

Comment: Is this "favorites" only visible to me?

Comment: @Mark Can you find a way to see my favorites? If not, then yes.